# Populating text box from table, but getting string to int conversion errors

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net table that is collecting data. Two of the values to be collected are done via dropdownlist controls that are populated from data tables. The dropdownlists appear to be working correctly, but the save process is throwing errors for "cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'. All the values for the numeric values are already int and I can't figure out where the string is being introduced.

Here is the code behind one of the two instances:

class to build the table:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace cs1.Models
    {
    public class ItemBank
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Key]
        public int BankID { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Item Bank")]
        public string BankName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code for the dropdownlist:

```
  <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="LabelItemBank" runat="server">Item       Bank:</asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDItemBank" runat="server" ItemType="cs1.Models.ItemBank" 
                SelectMethod="GetItemBank" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                DataTextField="BankName" DataValueField="BankID" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Code for the query behind dropdownlist:

```
public IQueryable GetItemBank()
{
        var _db = new cs1.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable query = _db.ItemBank;
        return query;
    }
```

Code for the storing of records:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using cs1.Models;

namespace cs1.Logic

{
public class AddQuestion
{
    public bool Add_Question(string Author, string ImageFile, String  SubmitDate, string Stem, string RespA, string RespB, string RespC, string RespD, string RespE,
        string Answer, string Critique, string KeyObjective, string References, string Time, int Bank, int CatCode)
    {
        var myquestion = new Questions();
        myquestion.Author = Author;
        myquestion.ImageFile = ImageFile;
        myquestion.SubmitDate = SubmitDate;
        myquestion.Stem = Stem;
        myquestion.RespA = RespA;
        myquestion.RespB = RespB;
        myquestion.RespC = RespC;
        myquestion.RespD = RespD;
        myquestion.RespE = RespE;
        myquestion.Answer = Answer;
        myquestion.Critique = Critique;
        myquestion.KeyObjective = KeyObjective;
        myquestion.References = References;
        myquestion.Time = Time;
        myquestion.Bank = Bank; 
        myquestion.CatCode = CatCode; 


        using (ProductContext _db = new ProductContext())
        {
            // Add Product to DB.
            _db.Questions.Add(myquestion);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Success.
        return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Code for the Question class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace cs1.Models
{
public class Questions
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Author Name")]
    public string Author { get; set; }// change to authorID?

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Image File Name")]
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }

    [Required,  StringLength(20), Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public string SubmitDate { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "Stem"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Stem { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Response A")]
    public string RespA { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Response B")]
    public string RespB { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Response C")]
    public string RespC { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Response D")]
    public string RespD { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Response E")]
    public string RespE { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(1), Display(Name = "Correct Answer")]
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "critique"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Critique { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(500), Display(Name = "Key Learning Objective")]
    public string KeyObjective { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "References"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string References { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(5), Display(Name = "TimeAllowed")]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    [Required,  Display(Name = "Item Bank")]
    public int Bank { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Category Code(s)")]
    public int CatCode { get; set; }
}
}
```

Code behind on the submission form where error is flagged:

```
using cs1.Logic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace cs1.Submit

{
public partial class Submit_Form : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string productAction = Request.QueryString["ProductAction"];
        if (productAction == "add")
        {
            LabelStatus.Text = "Question Accepted!";
        }

    }
    public IQueryable GetCatCodes()
    {
        var _db = new cs1.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable query = _db.CatCode;
        return query;
    }
    public IQueryable GetItemBank()
    {
        var _db = new cs1.Models.ProductContext();
        IQueryable query = _db.ItemBank;
        return query;
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dt = Request.Form[txtDate.UniqueID];
    }

    protected void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Boolean fileOK = false;
  String path = Server.MapPath("~/Submit/Images/");
  if (ImageFile.HasFile)
  {
    String fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ImageFile.FileName).ToLower();
    String[] allowedExtensions = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".zip"};
    for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
    {
      if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
      {
        fileOK = true;
      }
    }
  }

  if (fileOK)
  {
    try
    {
      // Save to Images folder.
      ImageFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + ImageFile.FileName);
      // Save to Images/Thumbs folder.
      ImageFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + "Thumbs/" + ImageFile.FileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      LabelStatus.Text = ex.Message;
    }

    // Add question data to DB.
    AddQuestion questions = new AddQuestion();
    bool addSuccess = questions.Add_Question(AuthorName.Text, 
        ImageFile.FileName,
        txtDate.Text, 
        Stem.Text, 
        ResponseA.Text, 
        ResponseB.Text, 
        ResponseC.Text, 
        ResponseD.Text, 
        ResponseE.Text,
        DDResponse.SelectedValue, 
        Critique.Text, 
        KeyLO.Text, 
        Reference.Text, 
        DDTime.SelectedValue, 
        DDItemBank.SelectedValue,
        DDCategory.SelectedValue);
    if (addSuccess)
    {
      // Reload the page.
      string pageUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Count() - Request.Url.Query.Count());
      Response.Redirect(pageUrl + "?ProductAction=add");
      LabelStatus.Text = "Question addes Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
      LabelStatus.Text = "Unable to add question to database. Review comments next to fields";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    LabelStatus.Text = "Unable to accept file type.";
  }
}

    public MembershipUser currentuser { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: You should show your Questions class. All parameters of `Add_Question` are strings and i'm pretty sure that there is at least one that should be an `int`. Where do you get the error?

Comment: Added code for question class. The error is generating on the DDItemBank.SelectedValue line on the second item I just added

Comment: you haven't shown `Questions` class

Comment: you have shown far too much of your code, but still not the class `Questions`. I think it's auto generated, but i'm pretty sure that not all properties are strings

Comment: The editor did not recognize as code, now it should

Comment: Realized I copied the same item twice, not added the questions class. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only strings to the method `Add_Question` but two of the properties are ints. The method [`ListControl.SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) returns strings:

```
bool addSuccess = questions.Add_Question(AuthorName.Text, 
        ImageFile.FileName,
        txtDate.Text, 
        Stem.Text, 
        ResponseA.Text, 
        ResponseB.Text, 
        ResponseC.Text, 
        ResponseD.Text, 
        ResponseE.Text,
        DDResponse.SelectedValue, 
        Critique.Text, 
        KeyLO.Text, 
        Reference.Text, 
        DDTime.SelectedValue, 
        DDItemBank.SelectedValue,
        DDCategory.SelectedValue);
```

The problematic parameters are the last two, `DDItemBank.SelectedValue` and `DDCategory.SelectedValue`. You have to convert them to `int`:

```
int bank    = int.Parse(DDItemBank.SelectedValue);
int catCode = int.Parse(DDCategory.SelectedValue);
```

Then pass these parameters to `Add_Question`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works, very similar to what Tim Schmelter posted (thanks Tim!):

```
// Add question data to DB.
AddQuestion questions = new AddQuestion();
bool addSuccess = questions.Add_Question(AuthorName.Text, 
    ImageFile.FileName,
    txtDate.Text, 
    Stem.Text, 
    ResponseA.Text, 
    ResponseB.Text, 
    ResponseC.Text, 
    ResponseD.Text, 
    ResponseE.Text,
    DDResponse.SelectedValue, 
    Critique.Text, 
    KeyLO.Text, 
    Reference.Text, 
    DDTime.SelectedValue, 
    Convert.ToInt32(DDItemBank.SelectedValue),
    Convert.ToInt32(DDCategory.SelectedValue));
if (addSuccess)
```